# Rails 5: Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Building websockets app based off of actioncable-examples.  When starting server, running rake, etc.  I keep getting the message:

```
Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated.
```

Haven't seen a solution here, but did find one.  I wanted to post the question and answer here so that it's available.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I found the answer in RubyGems issue #1551 [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1551).  The binstubs, the files in the bin folder, need to be updated.  The best way to do this is:

```
bundle update spring
bundle exec spring binstub --remove --all
bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

And that resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also face same error in my `rails 4.2.7` application and I fixed the error to update `bin/spring` file line no 11

```
Gem.paths = { 'GEM_PATH' => [Bundler.bundle_path.to_s, *Gem.path].uniq.join(Gem.path_separator) }
```

Comment: This answer is useful because it points down to the root cause of the issue. However, the accepted answer above gives instructions to regenerate that same binstub file, which should be safer because there is no risk of putting the wrong code in by hand.

Answer (score -1):

**tl;dr** `bin/spring binstub`, you might need to update `spring` before that (if 1.3.3 <= `spring` < 1.6.4).

`spring` had been using an array for the `GEM_PATH` value in its binstubs since [1.3.3](https://github.com/rails/spring/commit/c2aafcfa0eed4bd62b971fd868bdcccebdd48407#diff-75bd83565389d1cdfbd3d56c3414272fadd7aba5e9d0a892059bce5dcaea0fabR40) till [1.6.4](https://github.com/rails/spring/commit/e31716d8654520cde26d61d271e6eca1d5c02192#diff-75bd83565389d1cdfbd3d56c3414272fadd7aba5e9d0a892059bce5dcaea0fabR41).

In `rubygems-2.6.0` they were planning to [give up on arrays](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/27a436e91f1d83dc4a23168851d4d29a73fde752#diff-14c3102878b81a4dd5aed636d74aa3c20f7f10e8dff57cf4117b427e7dadef93L58), but apparently those binstubs made its way in a lot of projects. So they [restored the array handling](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v2.6.1/History.txt#L9-L10) in [`rubygems-2.6.1`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/a6b69e94232166dda441bbb69b64cf90562eebfd#diff-dd90140a6483cfb50fbbc3268f0d77984cd96e17792201e53bb3c0dc7ec435f9R360), but with a deprecation warning. Those 2 correspond to [Ruby 2.4.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/5a90f9e8f84533e7859232895fc4bbe6b31cc771).

Comment: bundle update spring was the first command?

Comment: @Richard_G Was? It is, if you're running `1.3.3 <= spring < 1.6.4`. For `spring >= 1.6.4` it is not required.

Comment: @Richard_G Actually I'm okay if you replace your answer with mine. Then I can delete mine. I'm just not sure if you agree.