# rvm PATH error running rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've created a rails application with rails 5, but running command

```
rails s
```

I got this error

```
Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated.
Please use a String or nil.
An Array ({"GEM_PATH"=>["/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2", "/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global"]}) was passed in from bin/rails:3:in `load'
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
 ... 5010 levels...
from /home/davide/Scrivania/Led2/bin/spring:13:in `require'
from /home/davide/Scrivania/Led2/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  bundle update spring && bundle exec spring binstub --remove --all && bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

taken from https://gist.github.com/webdev1001/e848abef8064c55c2f6443a282f75651

Comment: it gave me "Bundler attempted to update spring but its version stayed the same"

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1551)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864054/rails-5-array-values-in-the-parameter-to-gem-paths-are-deprecated)

Run `bundle update spring && bundle exec spring binstub --remove --all && bundle exec spring binstub --all` on your terminal.

Comment: it gave me "Bundler attempted to update spring but its version stayed the same"