# c9 - rails looks to be running - can't access the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c9.io

Can't access my ROR app.

On c9 workspace and I start ROR app and get this output

```
`Array values in the parameter to 
`Gem.paths=` are deprecated.
Please use a String or nil.
An Array ({"GEM_PATH"=>["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@global"]}) was passed in from bin/rails:3:in `load'
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2018-07-02 22:39:12] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-07-02 22:39:12] INFO  ruby 2.3.4 (2017-03-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2018-07-02 22:39:12] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1685 port=3000 '
```

however when I try to access the app using http://localhost:3000
I get this message

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Did you mean http://localhost3000.org/?
```

It looks like app is running however I can't access it.  Why ?

Comment: Have you already taken a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/webdev1001/e848abef8064c55c2f6443a282f75651) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864054/rails-5-array-values-in-the-parameter-to-gem-paths-are-deprecated)?

Comment: Never used c9 but it would appear you have a personal domain in the format of http://workspacename-username.c9users.io/, check this:
https://community.c9.io/t/running-a-rails-app/1615.  It specifically says "Do not try to access the project through the IP address and port number rails returns to you–it won’t work!"

Comment: Julian - Thanks I followed this which removed error comments when I start the Rails app

Comment: numbers1311407- thanks this is probably what is happening - have been trying different web addresses but still unalble to access the web page